# How to view Favorites list from the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, stack-exchange

How do I view list of **Stack Overflow** Favorites from the Stack Exchange Android app?

On the Stack Overflow site, I can see Favorites under Activity -> Favorites:

[image: Favorites]

However, I do not see this option on the Stack Exchange Android app.

This is a link of [Stack Exchange Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en).

Answer (score 3):

There is no Favourites menu option in the Android app, but you can search for the following term:

```
infavorites:mine
```